# "Simple FB Connect" module return page not found when user path replace with another module called "Rename Admin Paths"

Tags: 7

Hi I am using "Rename Admin Paths" module for replace "user" path to "account" & working good. But today when I am trying to integrate "Simple FB Connect" module with my drupal 7 site, it return Page Not Found - when try to navigate domain.com/account/simple-fb-connect. But when i try domain.com/user/simple-fb-connect after disable rename_admin_paths module, its working, i can connect with facebook.

I am trying to replace all 'user/simple-fb-connect....' path to 'account/simple-fb-connect....' into simple_fb_connect modules files, but no luck!

Can anyone help me please... how can i configure simple_fb_connect with rename_admin_paths module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

after 2 days, i solved my problem by change 'user/simple-fb-connect' to 'connection/simple-fb-connect' and its now working.